# Gitlab Pipeline CI/CD .gitlab-ci.yml for Angular

Tags: angular, gitlab

I am new to CD with Gitlab and wants to add pipeline for Angular. Everything is working fine except I cannot be able to copy the dist folder from one location to another using the following commands mentioned below.

Below is my yml file

```
image: node:latest
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  environment: staging
  only:
    - staging
  script:
    - echo "$(ls -la)"
    - npm install
    - npm install -g @angular/cli
    - ng build --prod --build-optimizer --progress=false
    - echo "$(ls -la dist/)"
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - cp -R ~/builds/KtpUrx12/0/root/admin/dist/ /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/staging.domain.com
      - chown -R myadmin:admin /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/staging.domain.com
```

The copy command is giving me the error of "no matching files". Also, the same error I am getting for chown.

What I'am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have an updated .yml that you can share that shows how the heck to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I take is to run two stages, the first I cache the files, the second I use those files to deploy. I don't use the artifacts feature, so I cannot comment on how it works, but it's possible the files are no longer available by the time it gets executed.

Note how I use `cache` inside `build_stage` to cache the `/dist` folder for use in `deploy_stage`.

I've also shown how I copy across servers using `scp`, which may come in handy. It can also copy to `127.0.0.1`.

```yaml
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_stage:
  stage: build
  only:
    - staging
  cache:
    paths:
      - dist/
  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer --progress=false

deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  environment: staging
  only:
    - staging
  script:
    - scp -r dist/my-app/* $STAGING_SERVER_URI:/opt/staging/my-app
```